# Extra collapsed fieldset on node form

Tags: nodes, forms

I have an extra collapsed input format fieldset on my node form. It above all other elements, appears unrelated to any fields, and I can't tell where it's coming from. Not sure how to investigate where the source is.

I'm guessing that the Multistep module is the cause, but I need to at least figure out what field the form is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is to simply inspect the html of the form, it should have identifying markup in the HTML which you can then use to grep all your modules for.

Your second option is to implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and output $form to see which form is generating it and whether there are any identifying markers there. You can use kpr() to output the results of $form using the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module to get nicer looking output. You can also use hook_form_alter to remove the fieldset if you want.

Comment: My fault for not specifying, but I'd done all of that. The HTML has no classes to clue in the field, and dsm() on the form with a form_alter() doesn't really help since it's pre-render.

Comment: Are you performing hook_form_alter() or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to check the dsm() output?